# Probability of choosing a random object from a set

Tags: probability, statistics

So I am currently doing an assignment for statistics and the following problem is given:

There are 200 balls in a container with the following properties described in this table:

|  | Balls without stripes | Balls with stripes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Red Balls | 40 | 10 |
| Green Balls | 110 | 40 |

If one ball is randomly selected from these 200, find the probability that this ball:

1. is a ball without stripes
2. is a red ball and has no stripes
3. is a green ball OR a ball with stripes (Edited to OR)

I am not directly looking for an answer but for an approach how to solve this problem, since my gut feeling tells me that just calculating percentages (lets say for 1. that would be 40+110=150, 150/200=0.75 = 75%) is not correct here.

So I am looking for an approach on how to solve this problem and also very importantly I would like to know what these sort of problems are called so i can read into this topic.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Let's look at 1. first. How would you approach it?

Comment: You solved the first problem correctly.

Comment: My first thought is there are 40 red balls without stripes and 110 green balls without stripes that makes 150 balls without stripes. 150 out of 200 is 75% but i am pretty sure my approach is not correct :)

Comment: So for 2. it is 40 red balls without stripes out of 200 total is 20% and for 3. it is also 40 green balls with stripes out of 200 total, so also 20% ?

Comment: P(Not solid red)  = 1 - 40/200 = (10+40+110)/100.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to open with what will seem like an extremely pedantic statement.

Just saying that a ball is "randomly" chosen is not enough to give the probability.

Whenever we make a random choice, we must describe the probability distribution of the random choice. In this case, we can describe it by saying that we're randomly picking a ball from the urn such that each ball is equally likely.

This means that each individual ball must have a probability of $\frac{1}{200}$ of being selected.

Now that we have this vital piece of information, we can turn to solving your problem.

Since each ball has a $\frac{1}{200}$ chance of being selected and there are $40 + 110 = 150$ balls without stripes, there is a $150 \cdot \frac{1}{200} = \frac{150}{200} = \frac{3}{4}$ chance of picking a ball without stripes.

Since each ball has a $\frac{1}{200}$ chance of being selected and there are $40$ red balls without stripes, there is a $\frac{40}{200} = \frac{1}{5}$ chance of picking a red ball without stripes.

The last problem is similar.

Comment: Thank you for you detailed answer I just noticed that i misread the last question it actually has to be a green ball OR a ball with stripes so i came to the conclusion to use the inclusion exclusion principle in the following way: 150 (green balls) + 50 (balls with stripes) - 40 (green balls with stripes, since we counted those double) = 160 and 160/200 = 0.8 = 80%. I think that it's correct.

Answer (score 0):

A Venn diagram can be really helpful for problems like this.
[image]